# Why does my authenticated keep changing its value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a login page using react, but when creating the context and an authentication hook I had a problem, the value of "authenticated" does not persist in true, I performed some tests to see its values and I saw that it alternated between true and false, but I didn't identify a loop or anything like that.

```
import backend from "../utils/backend";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useAuth() {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(authenticated);

    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

    if (token && !authenticated) {
      authUser(token);
    }
  }, []);

  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(authenticated);
  }, 300);

  async function authUser(token) {
    backend.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${JSON.parse(token)}`;

    try {
      const data = await backend.get("/users/verify").then((res) => {
        return res.data;
      });
      console.log(data, "response from back-end");
      setAuthenticated(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  return { authenticated };
}
```

[the console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk6XT.png)

I tried to recreate the system, I changed the authUser function to setAuthenticated(true), but nothing I did worked

Answer (score 0):

From react official document, you can learn about the custom hook.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

> Do two components using the same Hook share state? No. Custom Hooks
> are a mechanism to reuse stateful logic (such as setting up a
> subscription and remembering the current value), but every time you
> use a custom Hook, all state and effects inside of it are fully
> isolated.

So, whenever you use `useAuth` in the separated components, it creates isolated state like `useState`. If you want to persist the value, you will need to use `useContext` or `Redux`